# Find the element from the array on the page [JS]

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

Greetings Stackoverflow community!
First time here, so please sorry if I did something wrong. 
I'm a noob in code but face the problem that I need to make a small plugin for searching the specific link on the page. The code below is a part of different examples or code from other StackOverflow answers.

So the plugins work except 2 things:

1. It spam "nothing found" on every link, as I suggest, and it should be some kind of summarize if my link didn't find at all
2. Counter didn't work and I have no actual clue, but sure my knowledge isn't enough to complete it.

```
const countersNEW ={};
var linkHrefs = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), link => link.href);
var searchLinks = ['domain.tld'];

linkHrefs.some(href => {
  const index = searchLinks.findIndex(link => href.includes(link));
 searchLinks.forEach((val, index) => countersNEW[index] = 0);
if (index != -1)
{
 countersNEW[index] ++;
 alert("site FOUND!!!!!!", 'countersNEW');
return true; 
 }
 else 
{
 alert("nothing found");
 return false; 
 }});
```

So after I click on it the plugin should display 1 alert if there any site what I add to my array found or not. Would be pleased for any help.

Comment: *"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"* [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: After I use the plugin on the page with a link from my array it spams with alert  "nothing found" till the last alert where it shows that site is actually here. How can I remove all these spam alerts and make just 1 alert if there site from the array on the page?

Comment: @Leonard Please [edit] your question to add a the proper title (the one you just mentioned here is most likely too long). Being new here isn't a problem, but in that case we really recommend to read the [tour] and [ask] pages. Stack Overflow is a bit different from other communities. The goal of questions is to be helpful to future readers as well, so our standard for questions is high.

Answer (score 0):

`searchLinks.forEach((val, index) => countersNEW[index] = 0);` you're overriding here your outer index variable with the `index` from `forEach` callback.

Try changing it to `searchLinks.forEach((val, i) => countersNEW[index] = 0);` and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Stil the same, about 20 alerts that nothing found and the last said that there actually site what I'm looking for on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you want to do with the countersNew, if you want the number, you can just do something like this:

```
const countersNEW = 0;
var linkHrefs = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), link => link.href);
var searchLinks = ['domain.tld'];

linkHrefs.forEach(href => {
  if (searchLinks.includes(href)) {
    countersNEW++;
    alert("site FOUND!!!!!!", countersNEW);
    return true;
  }
});

alert("nothing found");
return false;
```

---

To avoid having a "nothing found" each not matching link, just take the alert out of the forEach loop.
In your code, you are telling the plugin to give you the message **for each** element that is not in your searchLinks.

Comment: CountersNEW should add in the alert number of sites what was founded on the page. 
As far as I know, I cant user '0' because in array 'searchLinks' I will use more than I domain. Correct me if I wrong.

Comment: It starts as 0 but for every match, it increases by 1, and displays the message.

Comment: @Leonard By the way, do you plan searching for more than one link?